# How to compare templatebase64 of live fingerprint with those stored in database using Secugen WebApI

Tags: biometrics

I'm using Secugen Hamster Plus as finger reader with their Web API SDK. I have been able to save fingerprint templatebase64 to my SQL database, what they have in their sample code is JavaScript functions which you can use to compare two fingers on client web browser in this case both the two template are being captured on the same. My requirement is that I want to take the template of live scan finger and compare with it those stored in database. The sample given by the manufacturer don't seem to tackle this problem.

Comment: Its simple just scan and check what you scan with what has been stored already...

Answer (score 0):

You actually need, server side comparison instead of the client side comparison. Secugen doesnt provide such features. You have to either develop your Automatic Finger Identification Algorithm by your own, or use the Fingerprint Matching services from

1. [CAMS](http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#compare-fingerprint)
2. [M2Sys](http://www.m2sys.com)
3. [Neurotechnology](https://www.neurotechnology)